# Django Forbidden 403 Error "CSRF token missing or incorrect" when trying to log in when already logged in

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-authentication, django-login

So I am using all built in Django, I don't have my own login view.

---

First I'll describe how the scenario is created that causes this error:

So someone is logged in and has multiple tabs open and then they log out. Eventually the other tabs will be directed to the accounts/login page either by themselves or the page is refreshed or a link is pressed, it doesn't really matter how. The point is this person now has multiple tabs that are all on the accounts/login screen and no one is authenticated/logged in.

So then this person successfully logs in in one of the tabs. They then go and to one of the other tabs, which are still on the accounts/login page (even though a session is already created).

If this person then tries to log in as the person logged in, or really anyone, in fact even if the username and password are empty and they simply click the login button, the `403 Error CSRF token missing or incorrect` gets thrown.

(I hope this makes sense)

Anyways, how can I fix this?

And this is my html template if that helps:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <div class='panel panel-primary' style='margin: 0 auto; max-width: 360px;'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
      <h3 class='panel-title'>Login</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
      <form action='{% url 'login' %}' novalidate='novalidate' role='form' method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <input type='hidden' name='next' value='{{ next }}' />
        <div class='form-group' style='margin-bottom: 0;'>
          <p>
            <small>
              By using this site, you agree to our
              <a href='{% url 'privacy-policy' %}'>privacy policy</a>
              and
              <a href="{% url 'terms-of-use' %}">terms of use</a>.
            </small>
          </p>
          <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Edit:**

I would also like to add that if I create the same scenario and instead of immediately trying to log in, instead I reload the page just once, the 403 error doesn't happen.

I just want to be able to prevent users from ever running into an error while using the site (outside of typing things directly into the search bar of course). One idea could be that right when login is clicked it will refresh the csrf token the same way a page refresh would, is this possible and a good idea?

Comment: can you share login view as well?

Comment: I don't have my own login view, I just use the one django provides.

Comment: Are you using `@csrf_protect` decorator?

Comment: I am not using `@csrf_protect` anywhere in my code.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: "check my answer" What answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears I've found a solution that doesn't exactly solve the error directly but it does avoid the situation where the error would happen. The behavior is a little bit different, but it works really well for me and I assume it will be the same most of the time for others.

So first, I reroute away from the login page whenever the user is already logged in. I accomplish this with creating my own login view:

```
class LoginView(LoginView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get("next") or "/")
        else:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Second, I made it so every time the window becomes "focused" (i.e. you switch to the tab) a simple ajax request is sent to check if the user is authenticated, if they are, the window will be reloaded, thus bringing them to the correct page.

To accomplish this I added this javascript to the `login.html` page:

```
{% block extrascripts %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script>
      "use strict";

      window.onfocus = function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/accounts/status/",
          success: function(result, status, xhr) {
            if (result.is_authenticated) {
              window.location.reload();
            }
          }
        });
      };
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And added this view:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="get")
class StatusView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({"is_authenticated": request.user.is_authenticated})
```

And I also updated the URLs as well of course.

---

I'll also add that if you don't want to be redirected away from login page when already authenticated, you can leave that code out and it should still fix the error, considering I wasn't having the error when I would reload the page first before trying to log in.

Answer (score 1):

it will happen because, For security reasons, the value of the secret is changed each time a user logs in.

- In every Django form, you have a hidden input called "CSRF token" or `{% csrf_token %}`.
  This value is randomly and uniquely generated at the time the form
  rendered and will be compared after the request has been made. So the
  request can only be sent from the authorized user's browser. There is
  no way (which I know of) an attacker can get this token and perform
  the malicious request that can be accepted by Django backend.

> For all incoming requests that are not using HTTP GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
>   or TRACE, a CSRF cookie must be present, and the ‘csrfmiddlewaretoken’
>   field must be present and correct. If it isn’t, the user will get a
>   403 error.
>        When validating the ‘csrfmiddlewaretoken’ field value, only the secret, not the full token, is compared with the secret in the cookie
>   value. This allows the use of ever-changing tokens. While each request
>   may use its own token, the secret remains common to all. This check is
>   done by CsrfViewMiddleware.

for more details [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#how-it-works)

Comment: Well, the way it acts just seems buggy. Like if I create the same scenario and instead of immediately trying to login, I reload the page just once, the `403` error doesn't happen. I just want to prevent users from ever running into a bug while using the site outside of typing things directly into the search bar.

One idea could be that right when login is clicked it will refresh the csrf token the same way a page refresh would, is this possible and a good idea?

Comment: what about if u make a simple check if user is logged in.If he is already login just redirect him/her to his profile page?

Comment: I'm thinking this is a good solution. However, this won't fix the problem when someone else tries to log in. It might be confusing that someone logs in with their credentials and after clicking login it goes to an account that isn't what they logged in as. 

In this situation, I would rather have it log out the person out who is currently logged in, and then proceed to log in with the given credentials. This is how it works if someone simply reloads the page first and then logs in.

Comment: There isn't a standard way to to avoid the 403 when you submit from a stale tab. Are you sure it's a problem in practice? You're more likely to have multiple tabs open and run into this problem during development/testing. If you really do need to fix the behaviour, I think you'll need JavaScript running on the page which detects the when the CSRF token was rotated and refreshes the page.

Comment: "I think you'll need JavaScript running on the page which detects the when the CSRF token was rotated and refreshes the page."

This is something. I might try to implement this. I honestly don't know much about how the CSRF token work. Would you know how to implement this? Or at least be able to direct me in the right direction?

Comment: You don't need javascript, you just need something to respond before the csrf middleware kicks in.  OR, make the login view CSRF exempt and handle it all in the view itself.